# Parsing an XML document and

Tags: c#, xml, foreach

I basically want to print out just the names of my XML document into a textbox.

All this does it print the first name.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("my documents address");
TextBox2.Text = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("Web_Service/Food/Name").InnerText;
```

What I'd like to do is something like this...

```
String[] output;

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("my documents address");

foreach(Name i in xDoc){
    append i to output;
}

TextBox2.Test = output;
```

Or something similar. If someone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

So it prints out:

Curry, Chicken, Burger, Steve, Spices, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ-to-XML as also suggested in @Selman's answer is a good option to look into. But in case you want to stick with `XmlDocument`, you can use `SelectNodes()` to get all matching nodes :

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
foreach(XmlNode name in xDoc.SelectNodes("Web_Service/Food/Name"))
{
    output.Add(name.InnerText);
}
TextBox2.Text = string.Join(", ", output);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you wanna just concatenate the values of `Name` elements ? If so, it can be done easily using [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");
var names = xmlDocument.Descendants("Name").Select(x => (string)x);
TextBox2.Text = string.Join(", ", names);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx

if you post the input xml i can get you the correspoding c# code